# How can I store BitLocker keys in a trusted platform module chip for a non-system drive in Windows?

Tags: windows, bitlocker

I've enabled BitLocker to use my laptop's TPM chip for the system drive, but how can I use the TPM chip for a non-system drive in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TPM only on the OS drive:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/enable-bitlocker?view=win10-ps#description

However, you can enable AutoUnlock if you don't want to provide your password to access your data drive every time:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/enable-bitlockerautounlock?view=win10-ps